# PHP Looping Through Replacing Tags

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to do custom tags for links, colour and bullet points on a website so [l]...[/l] gets replaced by the link inside and [li]...[/li] gets replaced by a bullet point list.

I've got it half working but there's a problem with the link descriptions, heres the code:

```
// Takes in a paragraph, replaces all square-bracket tags with HTML tags. Calls the getBetweenTags() method to get the text between the square tags
function replaceTags($text)
{
  $tags = array("[l]", "[/l]", "[list]", "[/list]", "[li]", "[/li]");
  $html = array("<a style='text-decoration:underline;' class='common_link' href='", "'>" . getBetweenTags("[l]", "[/l]", $text) . "</a>", "<ul>", "</ul>", "<li>", "</li>");

  return str_replace($tags, $html, $text);
}

// Tages in the start and end tag along with the paragraph, returns the text between the two tags. 
function getBetweenTags($tag1, $tag2, $text)
{
  $startsAt = strpos($text, $tag1) + strlen($tag1);
  $endsAt = strpos($text, $tag2, $startsAt);

  return substr($text, $startsAt, $endsAt - $startsAt);
}
```

The problem I'm having is when I have three links:

```
[l]http://www.example1.com[/l]
[l]http://www.example2.com[/l]
[l]http://www.example3.com[/l]
```

The links get replaced as:

```
http://www.example1.com
http://www.example1.com
http://www.example1.com
```

They are all hyperlinked correctly i.e. 1,2,3 but the text bit is the same for all links. 
You can see it in action [here](http://inkeep.org/articles/education/42/top-learning-resources/) at the bottom of the page with the three random links. How can i change the code to make the proper URL descriptions appear under each link - so each link is properly hyperlinked to the corresponding page with the corresponding text showing that URL?

Comment: are you sure the parameters get changed everytime you request the function?

Comment: I think whats happening is its getting given the whole paragraph containing 3 links, replacing each of the tags correctly but only calling the getBetweenTags() tags once then putting that description on each of the three links - how can i adapt the code to tell it to getBetweenTags() each time it encounters a new set of square tags?

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` does all the grunt work for you. The problem is that:

```
getBetweenTags("[l]", "[/l]", $text)
```

doesn't change. It will match 3 times but it just resolves to `"http://www.example1.com"` because that's the first link on the page.

You can't really do a static replacement, you need to keep at least a pointer to where you are in the input text.

My advise would be to write a simple tokenizer/ parser. It's actually not that hard. The tokenizer can be really simple, find all `[` and `]` and derive tags. Then your parser will try to make sense of the tokens. Your token stream can look like:

```
array(
    array("string", "foo "),
    array("tag", "l"),
    array("string", "http://example"),
    array("endtag", "l"),
    array("string", " bar")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would use preg_match_all instead personally.

```
$str='
[l]http://www.example1.com[/l] 
[l]http://www.example2.com[/l]
[l]http://www.example3.com[/l]
';
preg_match_all('/\[(l|li|list)\](.+?)(\[\/\1\])/is',$str,$m);
if(isset($m[0][0])){
    for($x=0;$x<count($m[0]);$x++){
        $str=str_replace($m[0][$x],$m[2][$x],$str);
    }
}
print_r($str);
```